# How to call endpoint from ajax where it redirects from controller to another view with data?

Tags: jquery, laravel, model-view-controller

Here i have search filter for web app, which take filter data and send it to controller method and controller do the filtering and redirect the page different one within controller. But this way it does not redirect to the result page.

here's the jquery script

```
function searchFilterData() {
    item = {};
    item.property_type = $('input[name=button-group]:checked').val();
    item.city = $('#property_city_drop_down').val();
    item.property_type2 = $('#property_type_drop_down').val();
    item.bath_roomes = $('#bath_rooms').val();
    item.bed_rooms = $('#bed_rooms').val();
    item.size = $('#square_foot').val();
    item.price_min = $('#price_min').val();
    item.price_max = $('#price_max').val();
    return item;
}

function post_method(URL, data) {
    console.log('POSTED');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'property/' + URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.status == true) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error !');
        }
    });
}
```

here's the laravel Controller method return statement,

```
return view('property.index', compact('paginatorData', 'paginatorData2', 'host', 'numberOfProperty'));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing to achieve this functionality?
Btw you can also also use route name for url like we do exactly in forms.
For excample
url: '{{route("routename")}}'